# Django. Change filed type UUIDField to CharField

Tags: django, postgresql, migration

I had in user model field:

```
class User(PermissionsMixin):

     id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True,
                           unique=True,
                           default=uuid.uuid4,
                           editable=False)
```

but i need to change this field on

```
class User(PermissionsMixin):

    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,
                              unique=True,
                              max_length=32,
                              default=uuid.uuid4,
                              editable=False)
```

I have postgre data base. when i did migrations i had error:

```
File "/home/alex/projects/Test/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.DatatypeMismatch: foreign key constraint "users_groups_user_id_f500bee5_fk_users_id" cannot be implemented
DETAIL:  Key columns "user_id" and "id" are of incompatible types: uuid and character varying.
```

Can you give me some advice, how i can to change field from `UUIDField` to `CharField`

Comment: Save whole table data in .json format (for example). Then drop table and create table again with id (CharField). After creation table, fill your table from .json data.

Comment: @gachdavit thanks for advice. It will be dangerous))

Comment: You welcome. postgresql can not cast this types, so...